# Finding first search value across columns and retrieving column details it was found in

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I was wondering if it was possible to determine from which column a coalesce value is drawn from?

I have the following example data (actual years range from 1989 - 2010 in data, not shown for brevity)

```
ID    |   2000  | 2000 value | 2001  |2001 value |  2002  |2002 value | 2003  |2003 value |  2004  | 2004 value | 2005 | 2005 value
id001 |  single | 15.46      |regular|50         | NULL   | 0         |single | 152       | regular|15.20       |single| 15.99
id002 | regular | 20.46      |regular|17.99      |single  | 150.23    |both   |  256.3    | NULL   |  0         | NULL |  0
```

Where single / regular / both reflect how that ID paid for something in that year (and NULL represents no purchases).

What I would ideally like to have is a three columns per year for the years 2005-2010 tells you the most recent single payment type before that year (and in which year it falls), as well as a column for regular and both payment types

So for the example above the results would look like:

```
ID    |   2005 prior single year  |  2005 prior regular year  |  2005 prior both year
id001 |   2003                    |  2004                     | NULL
id002 |   2002                    |  2001                     | 2003
```

I would also like to be able to pull out the respective values as well (for all years 2005-2010).

Fundamentally it's just a case of looking across columns to find the first instance, but beyond some kind of coalesce I'm not sure how best to approach this!

Thanks! :)

Comment: I so don't like data structures which aren't normalized. Makes writing a query equal to hell. Maybe it would make sense to transform the data into a 3rd normal form compliant data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd write a view to normalize the data:

```
select  2000 as year
,       [2000 value] as value
,       [2000 type] as type
from    YourTable
where   year = 2000
union all
select  2001
,       [2001 value]
,       [2001 type]
from    YourTable
where   year = 2001
....
```

Then you can look up the first year before 2005 like:

```
select  a.year [prior to 2005]
,       a.value
,       a.id
from    YourView a
where   year = 
        (
        select  max(year) 
        from    YourView b 
        where   a.id = b.id 
                and a.type = b.type 
                and b.year < 2005
        )
```

Once you have the normalized data, you can create many variations on this theme.

Comment: The problem with this is that I am looking for not just the most recent year, but the most recent year of the same type, so the where clause would need to also include WHERE 2005 = single and the result of the where clause also equals single, which is the main problem I am struggling with! Thanks

Comment: @Davin: You could check for type and id equality in the where clause?  Answer edited

Answer (score 1):

From the existing table, try:

```
select ID,
       case 'single'
           when [2004] then '2004'
           when [2003] then '2003'
           when [2002] then '2002'
           when [2001] then '2001'
           when [2000] then '2000'
           else NULL
       end [2005 prior single year],
       case 'regular'
           when [2004] then '2004'
           when [2003] then '2003'
           when [2002] then '2002'
           when [2001] then '2001'
           when [2000] then '2000'
           else NULL
       end [2005 prior regular year],
       case 'both'
           when [2004] then '2004'
           when [2003] then '2003'
           when [2002] then '2002'
           when [2001] then '2001'
           when [2000] then '2000'
           else NULL
       end [2005 prior both year]
from YourTable YT
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately as my year range spans from 1989 to 2010 it's not really very practical to have this case statement, as it will get rather large for the later years!

Comment: @Davin: copy and paste, my friend! Seriously, this is why normalistion is a better approach in the long run - this was a "quick-and-dirty" one-off solution.